# Show view result of both flagged users and the flagging user

Tags: 7, views, flags

I have a views listing the user profile of the users I have flagged by adding a relationship `flag`, and user profile. Then adding a contextual filter `uid` for the current user. I want the view to also show the profile of the user himself but it's showing profile of only the flagged users and it's not showing the profile of that user himself.

I want the result to be a combination of the current user, and the flagged users. How to do this?

Comment: flag relationship, do not require; uncheck "show flagged content only" add 2 fields on username, one without relationship and the other using relationship, and tell me how it goes. an image with your settings may help

Comment: Thanks   but this only adds a field to the rows. I want the current user's profile to show on another row, and not in d row of the flagged users profile

Comment: the idea to add 2 fields is that you can see what is happening in your view, and play arround with fields and relationships, inside relationships play with second relationship depends or not with the other and with your flags until you reach your goal.

Comment: This has not helped